# Export HTML containing MathJax results

Tags: javascript, html, css, mathjax

I use `QWebEngineView` to convert Markdown to HTML and render the math formula via MathJax. All the content are inside a `<div id="placeholder">`. Then I use `document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML` to get the HTML content, which contains the converted Markdown content and rendered MathJax output. At last, I output the HTML content to a HTML file.

However, when I open the exported HTML file via Chrome, the formulas lose the CSS styles like [this demo](http://js.do/tamlok/export_mathjax).

So any idea to make the formulas in order?

I have tried to add MathJax script to the exported HTML but the formulas will disappear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab not only the HTML, but also the CSS that MathJax's CommonHTML output jax produces, and the styles for the AssistiveMML extension (since your copied HTML includes its output as well).  The code below will obtain it for you.

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {
  var styles = document.head.getElementsByTagName("style");
  styles = [].slice.call(styles); // convert to array
  while (styles.length) {
    var sheet = styles.pop();
    if (sheet.innerHTML.match(/^(?:.mjx-chtml|.MJX_Assistive_MathML) \{/)) {
      document.getElementById("sheet").innerHTML += sheet.innerHTML;
    }
  }
});
MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {
  var math = document.getElementById("math");
  math.parentNode.removeChild(math);
});
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML"></script>

<span id="math">\(x\)</span>

<pre id="sheet">
</pre>
```

Put this into a `.css` file an link that to your page (or put it into a `<style>` tag in the document head).  That should do it for you.

Comment: Hi, when I add that code to the <style> </style> in the example above it doesn't render properly. Any idea why? You can see the code pasted into here https://js.do/code/export_mathjax

Comment: Your '<style>' tag is not closed, so the `<script>` ends up *inside* the `<style>` tag.  That means it will not be executed, and your stylesheet will be in error.  Also, the code tries to modify the stylesheet with `id="sheet"` as in the OP's original code.  Replace your `<style>` by `<style id="sheet"><./style>` and it will work.

Comment: @phubaba, forgot to tag you on my response above.

Answer (score 0):

Include the MathJax script in your HTML file:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'></script>
```

For some reason, the content is faded out and gets hidden, so the following styling is needed to stop the content from being hidden:

```
<style>
    .MJXc-processed {
        display: block !important;
    }
</style>
```

You can add that inside the HTML file's `head`

Comment: Thanks! But it now will duplicate the formula three times. We need to remove the duplicate `<span>` element. Any ideas to not let MathJax reprocess it but only style it? [demo](http://js.do/tamlok/export_mathjax_fix)